# converting go string to c string

Tags: go, cgo

In a program, I have a function that takes in a string argument, and returns a string in which `len(resultString)` could potentially be `4 * len(argumentString)`. This is because I am using `Cgo` with a C-file that I have imported into my project, and this C function requires a `char *` that is 4 times the original length of a string.

Is there an 'efficient' way of initializing and converting a go string to a C string? Because right now I am initializing a byte array in Go, and then `string`ing that, and then calling `C.CString` on that string. This ultimately is causing some performance issues if the length of the string is large enough. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient"? Do you want to skip the copy done by `C.CString`?

Comment: Maybe I worded it incorrectly. When I have a string `str` whose length is around `uint32 / 4` characters long, copying takes a significant amount of time. is this expected? If I don't want to do `C.CString` I'm assuming I would have to do that conversion using `cgo`.

Comment: Copying bytes, takes time. The only way to fix that is no not copy the bytes. I"m not sure what you mean by "do the conversion using `cgo`", `C.CString` is a `cgo` function.

Comment: C.Cstring allocates a *char and copies the argument into that newly allocated array. If you don't want to allocate an unnecessary string in Go, or if you don't need the copy, then alloc the memory in C. I can't be much more specific without any example to go by.